# Resolution of class template with different default template argument and partial specialization argument

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-specialization

I have two class (struct) templates `A` and `B`, which are identical except that the **second parameter's default argument** (in their primary templates) and the **template-specializing second argument** (in their partial specializations) are the **same in `A`** (both `void`), while **different in `B`** (`void` and `int` respectively).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

/* primary class template A */
template <int N, class = void>
struct A : std::false_type {};

/* partial specialization of A */
template <int N>
struct A<N, std::enable_if_t<(N != 0), void>> : std::true_type {};

/* primary class template B */
template <int N, class = void>
struct B : std::false_type {};

/* partial specialization of B */
template <int N>
struct B<N, std::enable_if_t<(N != 0), int>> : std::true_type {};

int main() {

    std::cout << A<0>::value << std::endl; // 0 (i.e. A<0> extends std::false_type)
    std::cout << A<1>::value << std::endl; // 1 (i.e. A<1> extends std::true_type)

    std::cout << B<0>::value << std::endl; // 0 (i.e. B<0> extends std::false_type)
    std::cout << B<1>::value << std::endl; // 0 (i.e. B<1> extends std::false_type)

    return 0;
}
```

As is understood from the output, `B<1>` resolves to the primary template whereas `A<1>` resolves to the partial specialization, which I guess happens due to the aforementioned difference. This is rather counterintuitive as I expected the exact opposite to happen. But why does it happen? How does the compiler decide which version to resolve, particularly in this case?

**Edit:**
As @Enlinco correctly identifies in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055765/13689844), my confusion was due to expecting that, when instantiating `B<1>`, the compiler would resolve the "more specialized for `N != 0`" version `B<N, int>`, preferring it to the "more generic" version `B<N, void>`.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You designed `A<int>` to default to `A<int, void>`, and then it uses the instantiation for `A<int, void>`.  You designed `B<int>` to default to `B<int, void>`, and then it uses the instantiation for `B<int, void>`. What would you expect anything else to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the confusion, when you see

```
/* primary class template B */
template <int N, class = void>
struct B : std::false_type {};

/* partial specialization of B */
template <int N>
struct B<N, std::enable_if_t<(N != 0), int>> : std::true_type {};
```

You think that when the compiler sees `B<1>` in `main`,

- it sees that the general template is ok,
- then it goes to see the specialization and

  - sees that `(N != 0)` is `true`,
  - resolves `std::enable_if_t<(N != 0), int>` to `int`
  - thus resulting in `B<1, int>`, which is good and to be preferred since it is a specialization.

The story is slightly different.

The line

```
template <int N, class = void>
```

just means, as suggested in a comment, that when you write `B<an-int>` the compiler sees `B<an-int, void>`.

If you look at it from this perspective, you should see why the mismatch causes the behavior you observe: `B<1>` is just `B<1, void>`, and no specialization is targeting that.